# Help with formatting list of equations font size

Tags: table-of-contents, equations

I have used this: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=428 to make a list of equations in my LaTeX document, but the "list of equation" formatting is different from the LOF and LOT formatting. Does anyone know how to change the formatting of the list of equations?

Comment: Thanks! it fixed the contents of the list! but the list of equations header is still larger than the LOF and LOT headers, got any tips on how the format the header?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to your document:

```
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
```

so that the linked MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}

\listofmyequations

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
   a=b
\end{equation}
\myequations{Equation number \ref{eq:Eq1}}

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq2}
   b=c
\end{equation}
\myequations{Equation number \ref{eq:Eq2}}  

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}` was just what I needed. Cheers.